# Microsoft Edge Compatibility

Tags: date, struts2, microsoft-edge

[image: Display of Date]

My application is currently using Struts 2.0. The date above are being displayed by the use of struts tag: **s:date**

It displays **invalid date** when I'm using MS Edge version 20.xxx but **WORKS FINE when I'm using MS Edge version 25.xxx up to the latest which is 40.xxx.**

I've been looking for documentation regarding compatibility of Microsoft Edge to Struts 2.0. Unfortunately, I can't find anything.. so far.

Any insights about this matter?

Comment: How do you use `<s:date>` tag?

Comment: And what's the date value? All `<s:date>` does is render--there's nothing being done on the client side.

Comment: What are your culture settings eg. en-US.... by any chance is it Norsk?